# Opening the user's home folder?

Tags: xul, xulrunner

My XULRunner application has a button named "Show Recordings". Pressing it should result in Windows Explorer opening the folder for the user. How can I achieve this?

I can't find it in the File I/O documentation, perhaps I'm looking in the wrong place.

**Edit**
The problem is not finding the path, but telling the system to open the folder. I can't seem to find a "openFolder" function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `reveal()` method on [nsILocalFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsILocalFile).

Comment: Yep, that's the one :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
  %HOMEPATH%
```

And by that I mean, if you want a global variable to get the current user's home directory path, use %HOMEPATH%.  I guess you have to set that button to this value. For a list of Windows environment variables, start at the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#User_management_variables).